# Single column footnote under \onecolumngrid in revtex4-1

Tags: footnotes, two-column, revtex

I am using `revtex4-1` with the argument `twocolumn`. In some part of the text I want to work under `\onecolumngrid`. However the footnote still appears in two-column format. How can I get a one-column footnote?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\onecolumngrid
\lipsum

Footnoted text.\footnote{\lipsum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated but note that `revtex4-1` is marked as obsolete, `revtex4-2` is the current supported one

Comment: @daleif Thanks. I actually use ‘revtex4-2’, but wasn’t sure whether this is standard now.

Comment: I think is has been for a while. Miktex does not even provide it anymore

Comment: Please try the updated answer.

Comment: You were right about the extra space. I corrected the code to make it similar to the one used in the normal two columns mode. Also changed the first figure. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: The commands with a @ inside are internal commands defined by the class. You have to read (with your .txt or .tex editor)   the file `revtex4-2.cls` and track the macro definitions, written in TeX. Then try to understand why do not work as expected, change them, and then check that nothing else got broken in the process. It is a great fun if you like programming.! Some people call this activity "hacking". In this case color white.

Comment: @SimonDispa Thank you so much for your update. Really appreciate your effort. Your suggestions are very helpful too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking the re-defined `\onecolumngrid` will make the following footnotes to use both two columns, until a `\twocolumngrid` returns to the footnotes and the text  to the two column mode.

A`\newpage` should be inserted  in the right place, before using `\twocolumngrid`  to switch to text to two columns, to start a new page in this mode.

Add this code to the preamble:

```
% ********************* added<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter 
    
\renewcommand\onecolumngrid{% <<<<<<
\do@columngrid{one}{\@ne}%
\def\set@footnotewidth{\onecolumngrid}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\def\footnoterule{\kern-6pt\hrule width 1.5in\kern6pt}%
}

\renewcommand\twocolumngrid{% <<<<<<
        \def\footnoterule{% restore rule
        \dimen@\skip\footins\divide\dimen@\thr@@
        \kern-\dimen@\hrule width.5in\kern\dimen@}
        \do@columngrid{mlt}{\tw@}
}%

\makeatother    
%%  ***********************************************
```

**Footnote using both two columns with \onecolumngrid**

[image: a]

**Back later to footnote and text in two  columns with \twocolumngrid**

[image: x]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,nofootinbib]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{lipsum}     
    
% ********************* added<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter 
    
\renewcommand\onecolumngrid{% <<<<<<
\do@columngrid{one}{\@ne}%
\def\set@footnotewidth{\onecolumngrid}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\def\footnoterule{\kern-6pt\hrule width 1.5in\kern6pt}%
}

\renewcommand\twocolumngrid{% <<<<<<
        \def\footnoterule{% restore rule
        \dimen@\skip\footins\divide\dimen@\thr@@
        \kern-\dimen@\hrule width.5in\kern\dimen@}
        \do@columngrid{mlt}{\tw@}
}%

\makeatother    
%%  *********************************************** 

\begin{document}
    
\onecolumngrid   
    
1. \lipsum[2-5]

\textbf{\Large Footnoted text 1.}\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\medskip
    
\textbf{\Large Footnoted text 2.}\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\medskip

\textbf{\Large Footnoted text 3.}\footnote{\lipsum[3]}

2. \lipsum[2-3]

\newpage % needed to start a new page with two columns

\twocolumngrid %back to two column

6. \lipsum[7-8]

\textbf{\Large Another footnoted text.}\footnote{\lipsum[1]}

\medskip
\textbf{\Large Another footnoted text.}\footnote{\lipsum[3]}        

9. \lipsum[9-15]    

\end{document
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However when two footnotes appear together, the horizontal line appears twice. Is there a easy fix for this? Thanks!

Comment: @WunderNatur Fixed. I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! One more minor issue: the space between the horizontal line and the footnotes seems too large to me. Or would you mind to explain your codes a little bit, so that I can modify them myself? I am pretty basic at TeX, and do not even understand `\do`, `@`, etc. Some references would also be great!